# I am not able to use Latex in word 2016 and have no access to word 2019, what other word processing program can I use?

Tags: pdf, msword

Basically I need a program where I can use LaTex as well, which produce a word document that can me converted to PDF file. Can someone help? I know that on Word

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please clarify your question? Why do you want to produce a word file out of latex code and later on convert the word file indo a pdf? Also, you mention using "latex in word". What do you mean with that?

Comment: LaTeX and Word are two (very) different worlds. PDF file is one of standard result of the compiling of  LaTeX files.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If you intend how to embed equation in Word, I'm afraid your question is off-topic here, try on SuperUser, see this post: https://superuser.com/questions/202806/how-to-import-latex-equation-into-ms-word-equation-or-into-mathtype?rq=1, for example.